# Getting NullPointerException while accessing the SuperClass method call using powermock

Tags: junit, powermock

Getting NullPointerException while accessing the SuperClass method call using powermock

While running the below mentioned testclass getting NullPointerException error at above mentioned line in switch(super.getType())

```
public class CommandParamInput extends AbstractCommandParam {
    public CommandParamInput(
            final ParameterFeedType commandParameterSourceToSet,
            final Object definedValueToSet) {
        this.commandParameterSource = commandParameterSourceToSet;
        this.definedValue = definedValueToSet;
    }
    public void evaluateValue(final FDPRequest fdpRequest)
                throws EvaluationFailedException {
        switch (super.getType()) {
          case ARRAY:
            evaluateComplexValue(fdpRequest);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

While running the below mentioned testclass getting NullPointerException error at above mentioned line in switch(super.getType())

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)   
@PrepareForTest({AbstractCommandParam.class,CommandParameterType.class,ParameterFeedType.class,LoggerUtil.class,Logger.class})
public class CommandParamInputTest {
    private Logger loggerMock;
    private FDPRequest instFDPRequest;
    private FDPResponse instFDPResponse;
    private FDPCacheable instFDPCacheable;
    private AbstractCommandParam cmdParam;
    private CommandParamInput spy;
    @Mock
    AbstractCommandParam absCommandParam;
    @Mock
    CommandParameterType cmdParameterType;
    @Mock
    ParameterFeedType parameterFeedType;
    @InjectMocks
    private CommandParamInput commandParamInput;
    @Before
    public void init() {
        FDPRequestImpl fdoRequestImpl = new FDPRequestImpl();
        fdoRequestImpl.setCircle(new FDPCircle(new Long(10),"10","test"));
        fdoRequestImpl.setChannel(ChannelType.USSD);
        instFDPRequest = fdoRequestImpl;
        spy = PowerMockito.spy(new CommandParamInput(parameterFeedType.AUX_REQUEST_PARAM, instFDPCacheable));
    }
    @Test
    public void testEvaluateValue()throws ExecutionFailedException,
    EvaluationFailedException, FileNotFoundException, RuleException{
        mockCommonObjects();
        commonMockExternalCall();
        absCommandParam = new CommandParamInput(parameterFeedType.AUX_REQUEST_PARAM, instFDPCacheable);
        absCommandParam.setType(cmdParameterType.PARAM_IDENTIFIER);
        PowerMockito.doReturn(cmdParameterType.PARAM_IDENTIFIER).when(spy).getType();
        // when(absCommandParam.getType()).thenReturn(cmdParameterType.PARAM_IDENTIFIER);
        PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.methods(AbstractCommandParam.class, "getType"));
        commandParamInput.evaluateValue(instFDPRequest);    
    }
}
```

Comment: No answer, just two comments: `switch (super.getType())` ... that looks super awkward. What is the point of calling super here? If you are overriding that method in the same class, calling the super version in other methods, that is really surprising. Really strange design ... and beyond that ... the whole code looks like it wasn't written to be easily tested. Thus you now have to do big leaps to somehow test it. My recommendation: step back, and invest your time into coming up with an "easier to test" design. And avoid PowerMock(ito) in the first place.